# Heroku, Django and celery on RabbitMQ

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery, gevent

I'm building a Django project on Heroku. 
I understand that gunicorn is recommended as a webserver so I need an event loop type of worker and I use gevent for that. 
It seems that monkey patching gevent does most of the work for me so I can have concurrency, but how am I supposed to connect to the RabbitMQ without real threads or jamming the whole loop?

I am baffled by this since Heroku themselves recommend gunicorn, celery and RabbitMQ but I don't see how all of these work together.

Comment: Gunicorn and Celery can use gevent. You can find it in their docs.

Comment: I saw gevent mentioned only in a headline, this does not mean what clients and/or transports support this. Can you please reference me to  a RabbitMQ client that officially supports gevent?

Answer (score -8):

Do you understand that celery and gunicorn are used for different purposes?

Gunicorn is the webserver responding to requests made by users, serving them web pages or JSON data.

Celery is an asynchronous task manager, i.e. it lets you run arbitrary python code irrespective of web requests to your server.

Do you understand this distinction?

Comment: Perhaps not. I think you can use celery with the gevent mode by setting a variable in the settings file.